# What is a TRSF connector?

Tags: cable

This [HOSA cable/adapter says it has a TRSF adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000068O5D). Is that a typo? What is TRSF?

Answer (score 9):

It is not a typo.

- TRS stands for tip, ring and sleeve. A TRS plug is the three-contact version of the TS plug (tip and sleeve).
- F stands for female. Male and female plugs of the same type can connect to each other.

The 1/4" TRSF to dual 1/4" TS cable is used to convert a TRS cable to two TS cables.